# Which group in an RE matched?

Tags: regex, dart

I have an RE in Dart with disjoint alternatives, i.e. either one alternative or none will match.  A trivial example:

```
var re = RegExp('(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)');

var m = re.matchAsPrefix('ab');
```

I want to know whether group A or B was the match (in real life there are lots more alternatives). In Python I write:

```
   matchedName = m.lastgroup
   matchedText = match.groupdict()[matchedName]
```

Is there an equivalent in Dart? `groupNames` returns A and B since they were both part of the search.

Comment: Note: there are no groups in the expression of yours.

Comment: Ryszard - Sorry - should have been '(?<A>a>)|(?<B>b)'

Answer (score -1):

If you make the individual options *capturing*, you can see which one actually matched:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r"(ab)|(cd)");
var m = re.matchAsPrefix("ab");
assert(m[1] != null); // Matched!
assert(m[2] == null); // Did not participate in the match.
```

A non-participating capture group will have the value `null`, which differs from a capture group which actually matched something, even the empty string.

For the example you gave:

```dart
var re = RegExp(r'(?<A>a)|(?<B>b)');
var m = re.matchAsPrefix('ab') as RegExpMatch;
assert(m.namedGroup("A") != null);
assert(m.namedGroup("B") == null);
assert(m[1] != null);  // Same as "A"
assert(m[2] == null);  // Same as "B"
```

If you have lots and lots of alternatives, it's a sizable overhead to keep track of all the alternatives, and you might want to consider other approaches than a RegExp. Still, it'll *work*.

There is no easier way to check participation. The Dart RegExp behavior must work when compiled to JavaScript, and the JavaScript match does not provide any more useful information.

Comment: Irn - It's a scanner experiment I was reimplementing in Dart as a learning exercise.  I could use a loop to test each option separately.  Your method makes sense except (I think) if the options themselves contained groups then I wouldn't know the numbering (the individual options are inputs to the scanner).

Comment: The numbering of capture groups is predictable (they are numbered by the order of the opening `(`). If nested capture groups should be treated differently, you would have to keep a separate list of the relevant indices. Or, alternatively, name every relevant capture group and use the names, but that would make for a very large RegExp.